# How to create single aab for multiple app flavours

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest, android-gradle-7.0

Is it possible to create a single aab for multiple application flavours in android.

Basically my requirement is to have have a application with one android manifest for Android SDK Version 26 to 32 and other manifest for Android SDK Version greater than 32

build.gradle

```
flavorDimensions "version"
productFlavors {
    flavour_one {
        dimension "version"
        minSdkVersion 26
        maxSdkVersion 32
    }
    flavour_two {
        dimension "version"
        minSdkVersion 33
    }
}

applicationVariants.all { variant ->
  
    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = "MyApplication-${getVersionName()}-${variant.name}.apk"
    }
}
```

my manifest structure is as below

```
project
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   └── AndroidManifest.xml
│   ├── flavour_one
│   │   └── AndroidManifest.xml
│   └── flavour_two
│       └── AndroidManifest.xml
```

on `gradlew bundleRelease` it is not creating single aab but instead creating two aabs

```
project
└── bundle
    ├── flavour_one
    │   └── MyApplication-flavour_one-release.aab
    └── flavour_two
        └── MyApplication-flavour_two-release.aab
```

1. is it possible to do ? if yes then where am i doing wrong
2. if no, is there any way i can achieve above requirement as google play console alows only one aab to upload against one project.

Comment: They would and should be considered completely separate apps